# Finding certain column names and locations in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

What are my input data:

- a triangular matrix stored in a pandas dataframe with defined index
  and column names
- a list of the same length as the number of columns in the dataframe
- a function that takes an item from the list as input

What I wish to do next:

- apply the function to the list based on the values in the dataframe
- plot the results of the function for each item from another list based on the columns of the data frame

A small example:

```
scores = np.array([[1,2,1.5,0.75],
                 [0,1,0.75,1.25],
                 [0,0,1,2],
                 [0,0,0,1]])
names = ['Andy','Bob','Craig','Dan']

bets = [100,120,135,130]

def getPrize(bet, x): # x defined somewhere elsewhere
    prize = bet*x #do stuff here
    return prize

names1 = ['Andy1','Bob1','Craig1','Dan1']

Results = pd.DataFrame(data=scores,index=names1,columns=names1)
```

Now, I define a condition on the values in the dataframe and based on that condition, I would like to find the position of the relevant column (the integer value as if -conversely- I was using df.iloc for finding it).

What I tried was this:

```
for i, r in Results.iterrows():
    found = r[r>1]
    col_index = r.columns.get_loc(found)
    print col_index
```

But here I face the problem that `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`.
But if I write this instead:

```
col_ix, col_name = found.iteritems()
```

I get `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` - so I am not using iteritems correctly? However, if I `print` the values, they are printed before the error is thrown.

Finally, I would like to have a single plot with the "prize" on y-axis and the names on x-axis, plotting the selected (by the condition) values of the prize for each person (and so the other thing that I am trying to achieve is to find which item of the `names` list is the substring of each of my resulting column names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest is only multiple:

```
print (results.mul(np.array(bets)))
        Andy    Bob   Craig    Dan
Andy   100.0  240.0  202.50   97.5
Bob      0.0  120.0  101.25  162.5
Craig    0.0    0.0  135.00  260.0
Dan      0.0    0.0    0.00  130.0
```

But if real function is more complicated use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def getPrize(bet,score):
    #working with Series score and list bets
    print (bet)
    print (score)
    prize = bet*score
    return prize

df = results.apply(lambda x: getPrize(bets, x), axis=1)
print (df)

        Andy    Bob   Craig    Dan
Andy   100.0  240.0  202.50   97.5
Bob      0.0  120.0  101.25  162.5
Craig    0.0    0.0  135.00  260.0
Dan      0.0    0.0    0.00  130.0

plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df.columns)), df.columns)
plt.plot(df.values)
```

EDIT:

If need positions of all columns is necessary `list comprehension` (or some loop), because [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) works only with scalars:

```
for i, r in Results.iterrows():
    found = r[r>1]
    col_index = [r.index.get_loc(x) for x in found.index]
    print (col_index)

[1, 2]
[3]
[3]
[]
```

Comment: I see! Thank you, good answer, but wrong question. It doesn't work for my real data and now I see why. I am going to edit the question.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking about your question and it depends of your function. Is your function really complicated and is not possible use pandas or numpy function(s) without apply?

Comment: If possible the best is add desired output, maybe also change input for better understanding. Thank you.

Comment: I changed the question now. Thank you for your patience.